# how to create 5 columns Sections In Blogger Template

Tags: html, blogger, sections

I am searching a way to create 5 columns Sections In Blogger Template my blog is https://social-bug.blogspot.com/

I have this code:

```
    <div id='footer-column-container'>
<div id='footer1' style='width: 225px; float: left; margin:0; '>
<b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-1' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
<b:widget id='Text1' locked='false' title='About B-G' type='Text'/>
 
</b:section>
</div>
 
<div id='footer2' style='width: 225px; float: left; margin:0; '>
<b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-2' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
<b:widget id='Text4' locked='false' title='About Author' type='Text'/>
</b:section>
</div>
 
<div id='footer3' style='width: 225px; float: right; margin:0; '>
<b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-3' preferred='yes' style='float:right;'>
<b:widget id='Text3' locked='false' title='Subscribe in Reader' type='Text'/>
</b:section>
</div>
 
<div id='footer4' style='width: 225px; float: right; margin:0; '>
<b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-4' preferred='yes' style='float:right;'>
<b:widget id='Text2' locked='false' title='Access B-G on Go' type='Text'/>
</b:section>
</div>

<div id='footer5' style='width: 225px; float: right; margin:0; '>
<b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-5' preferred='yes' style='float:right;'>
<b:widget id='Text5' locked='false' title='Access B-G on Go' type='Text'/>
</b:section>
</div>

 
<div style='clear:both;'/>
</div>
```

But the problem is I have no clue why these all 5 sections not aligned in the center please see the image here:
[Blogger Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGO3n.png)

Basically I want even sized sections and center all of the sections.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='footer-column-container' style='width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; '>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        /* Float four columns side by side */
        .footer-columns {
            float: left;
            width: 225px;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        /* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
        .footer-row {
            margin: 5px 5px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .footer-row:after {
            content: &quot;
            &quot;
            ;
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* Responsive columns */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
            .footer-columns {
                width: 20%;

            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            .footer-columns {
                width: 50%;

            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .footer-columns {
                width: 100%;

            }
        }


        /* Style the counter cards */
        .footer-columns {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <div Style='width: 100%;' class='footer-row'>
        <div id='footer1' class='footer-columns' >
            <b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-1' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
                <b:widget id='Text1' locked='false' title='About B-G' type='Text' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                        <b:widget-setting name='content' />
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <b:include name='widget-title' />
                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content />
                        </div>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>

        <div id='footer2' class='footer-columns' >
            <b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-2' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
                <b:widget id='Text4' locked='false' title='About Author' type='Text' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                        <b:widget-setting name='content' />
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <b:include name='widget-title' />
                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content />
                        </div>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>

        <div id='footer3' class='footer-columns' >
            <b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-3' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
                <b:widget id='Text3' locked='false' title='Subscribe in Reader' type='Text' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                        <b:widget-setting name='content' />
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <b:include name='widget-title' />
                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content />
                        </div>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>

        <div id='footer4' class='footer-columns' >
            <b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-4' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
                <b:widget id='Text2' locked='false' title='Access B-G on Go' type='Text' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                        <b:widget-setting name='content' />
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <b:include name='widget-title' />
                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content />
                        </div>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>
        <div id='footer5' class='footer-columns' >
            <b:section class='footer-column' id='footer-column-4' preferred='yes' style='float:left;'>
                <b:widget id='Text2' locked='false' title='Access B-G on Go' type='Text' visible='true'>
                    <b:widget-settings>
                        <b:widget-setting name='content' />
                    </b:widget-settings>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <b:include name='widget-title' />
                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <data:content />
                        </div>
                    </b:includable>
                </b:widget>
            </b:section>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```